General Advice for Deciding a PhD Experiment?
If you have already completed your Master's work and are considering several options for a PhD thesis topic, what factors are most important in deciding what is appropriate to continue working on for a PhD? While this question could be field-specific, I think more advice from a variety of fields could be more enriching for providing deeper insights.
I am specifically asking toward doing what is most feasible and practical but is a topic or area that will be interesting enough to have enough motivation to work toward for several years. PhD projects are your baby and you have to commit to working on a specific niche area of expertise.
My initial sense is that the findings from my Master's thesis should inform my PhD. However, I am not entirely sure  the findings are as simple and eleagant of a design that I imagined.
The factors I am currently weighing are whether it could be much simpler to implement. However, the tradeoff is whether it would be as novel or interesting. Additionally, I am trying to see if my supervisor would be willing to pursue an area that interests him more, because I am concerned if he would be able to invest time into guidance on a topic that is uninteresting. However the tradeoff could potentially be a topic that might not be too interesting to me.
So what should be prioritized most in deciding a thesis topic:

simplicity/ease of implementation vs. novelty and more work striking work that could have a lot of potential applications in different fields?
doctoral advisor's input and guidance in deciding a topic that motivates him to invest more in vs. a topic that interests me more?

Are there any additional factors worth considering in deciding a PhD topic?

I don’t think this is possible to address so generally. A lot of this depends on the people involved (at least you and the supervisor, but possibly also a research group) as well as the customs of the domain.

Choose the option where you learn the kinds of things you want to learn. (Too lazy to expand this into a proper answer.)

@mistermiyagi what if there is not a research group involved but moreso an option to get a few international collaborators involved in the more complex design yet with minimal assistance vs. a simpler design that has fewer people involved? I say this without being too specific at risk of getting flagged for "highly dependent on individual factors"

@Neurostar A few international collaborators is a research group, they just share less infrastructure/time/… than usual. It again depends on the people involved, how reliable/sociable/… they are.

Then the question is not dependent on any research team.. They are not the ones who decide the direction of the topic, only that there is an option to work with collaborators. I have a lot of flexibility over the design.

@Neurostar While the people want decide for you, they should be factored into your decision. For example, a "novelty and more work striking work" with an established research group has much higher success chance. Plus, "any additional factors worth considering in deciding a PhD topic" is going to be a long list of things depending on the circumstances.

A "simple and easy to implement" problem may not be sufficient for a doctoral research project. Generally more is required. In particular, one needs (generally) to come up with something that is publishable, which implies novelty and an extension to what is known.
An extension seen by experts as trivial  or obvious probably won't be accepted by those who judge the work, leading to failure to attain the degree, nor is it likely to be publishable.
Additionally, very few people can be successful in doctoral study unless their advisor "signs on" to their research project and is sufficiently skilled to assist when the going gets tough. There are a few but even those require an advisor who is willing to stand aside during the process but still approve the result.
So, your number 2 seems best and that probably implies a significant problem to be addressed. There are exceptions, but only for exceptional candidates. And those people don't need to take the easy path in any case.

To clarify, I am not looking for a design that is so distilled to be manufactured as a "trivial" research problem that sits on the desk of an editor in a pop science column only to be discarded by the reviewers. My current work (not only thesis) in some capacity supercedes that of some doctoral colleagues. However, the technical limitations can be such barriers that it can be difficult to replicate. And any open science published work should be written in that way. Not to mention the overemphasis on "novelty" in academia. See specific replication journals. https://aisel.aisnet.org/trr/
